# Cannot DataSet be exported TensorFlow CSV format

Tags: tensorflow, roboflow

i prepared my dataset and created a version of it. Then i tried to export dataset in **TensorFlow Object Detection CSV** format but when i got output of given zip file. But i see that there is nothing inside the zip file except "**README.roboflow.txt**" and "**README.Dataset.txt**"

Is there anything i'm doing wrong or it's in process of development ? or it's a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and was able to get my test, train, valid in the folder which also included the `README.Dataset.txt` and `README.roboflow.txt`.

Can you try again or share the email you used to build this project so one of us Roboflow staff members can take a look at it? You can feel free to dm it to me in our [forum](https://discuss.roboflow.com/) if it still doesn't work.

Kelly M., Developer Advocate